# Bootstrap modal ajax form submited many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I call form in modal using ajax, and using a modal button `.save-modal` the form is submitted using ajax. There are many submissions for the form and I don't know why?

The following code in the page -form- requested by  the modal:

```

```
@section('content')
<h1>kk</h1>
<div id="modal">
    {!! Form::model('App\Solution',['url' => $actionPath, 'id' => 'sForm', 'class' => 'form-inline']) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('title', __('Title')) !!}
    {!! Form::text('title',$solution->title,['class' =>'form-control']) !!}
    @php ($eleE =  $errors->first('title'))
     {{-- @include('layouts.form-ele-error') --}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('description', __('Description')) !!}
    {!! Form::textarea('description',$solution->description,['class' =>'form-control']) !!}
    @php ($eleE =  $errors->first('description'))
     {{-- @include('layouts.form-ele-error') --}}
    </div>

    {!! Form::close() !!}


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".save-modal").click(function(e){
            alert('many time alert') //
       e.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
           url: '{{$actionPath}}'+'/?'+Math.random(),  
           type: "POST",
           data: $("#sForm").serialize(),
           success: function(data){
               $("#modal-body").html($(data).find('#flash-msg'))

               $("#actions-modal").modal('hide')
               //return true;
           },
           error: function(xhr, status, response){
               if ( status == "error" ) {
                    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";

                    // $( "#modal-body" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
                    errors = xhr.responseJSON
                    console.log(errors)
                    $("#errors").html('');
                    $.each(errors,function(key, val){

                        console.log(key)
                        $("#errors").append('<span class="has-error help-block">'+val+'</sapn>')

                         //return false;
                    })
                    xhr.responseJSON = null;

                    }
                    return false;
           }
       })
       return false;
      })
      });
      </script>
   </div>
@endsection
```

The alert after `$(".save-modal").click(function(e){...` is alerted many time, specially when closing the modal and open it again with repeating trying of save invalidated entries the increase in alert is not fixed i.e it is the sum of invalidated data submission trying in the previous opening of the modal.

The following is the modal code on the base page:

```
$(".action-create").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).attr('href'))


    mhd = $(this).attr('title');//$(this).text()+' {{__("for Cavity")}}'+' '+$(this).attr('title');
    href = $(this).attr('href')



    //console.log(href)

    $("#actions-modal").on('show.bs.modal', function(){
            $("#modal-hd").html('<h4 style="display: inline">'+mhd+'</h4>');  
            $("#modal-body").html('<h4>{{__('Loading')}}<img src="/imgs/loading.gif" /></h4>')     
            gg(href)
            })

    $("#actions-modal").modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false        
        });
    });

    $("#actions-modal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){

        $("#modal-body").html('');
        $(this).data('bs.modal', null);
        //$(this).children('#errors').html('');
        $("#errors").html('');
        return false;

    });

    gg = function gg(){

        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: href,
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(data){
                    //console.log(data)
                    required = $(data).find("#modal");
                    $("#modal-body").html(required);
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, response ){
                    if ( status == "error" ) {
                    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                     $( "#modal-body" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText+ " With custom message:<br> "+ xhr.responseText );
                     //console.log(xhr)
                    }
                }

        });
        return false;
    }
```

I have tried to add `return false` in many parts of the code to cut any extra evaluation, I also tried to add random number to the ajax URL `Math.random()` but It seems that it executed many times.

There is also another form call on the same page called using the modal, and sometimes it be saved in addition to the called form!

Comment: @Roamer-1888 no, if you filled invalidated data, an error should be generated on the server-side `422` with response contains fields errors messages. However, the `alert` and console log shows that clicking on `Save Changes` i.e `.save-modal` is invoked several times after closing the modal and reopen it again with retrying to save invalidated data.

Comment: Because the user may forget to supply validated data. i,e leaving the title field empty. Again, it seems that it is not an error event related issue, the error shows it just because the modal remain opened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call form using ajax then you should keep in mind that javascript/jquery code of document ready is executed every time you receive response.

so, when you first open you model ".save-modal" click event is binded. when close and reopen the model. again request goes to server ajax content loaded in browser window and again a click event is binded. This way you end up with multiple anonymous function binded to single event. all will execute on same event.

solution 1 (recomanded): Declare function in saperate js file or inline which is included in main page (not ajax). Then instead of binding click event using jQuery. call function from onclick property of your ".save-modal" button.

solution 2: declare a global variable "IsAjaxExecuting". Test if this variable is true then return from you save function (this will stop mutliple execution). if it is not true then make it true. execute you ajax function. when response received then make it false again. eg.

```
var IsAjaxExecuting= false; // new code
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".save-modal").click(function(e) {
        if(IsAjaxExecuting) return; // new code
        IsAjaxExecuting = true; // new code

        alert('many time alert');
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{$actionPath}}' + '/?' + Math.random(),
            type: "POST",
            data: $("#sForm").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                IsAjaxExecuting = false; // new code
                $("#modal-body").html($(data).find('#flash-msg'))

                $("#actions-modal").modal('hide')
                //return true;
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, response) {
                IsAjaxExecuting = false; // new code
                if (status == "error") {
                    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";

                    // $( "#modal-body" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
                    errors = xhr.responseJSON
                    console.log(errors)
                    $("#errors").html('');
                    $.each(errors, function(key, val) {

                        console.log(key)
                        $("#errors").append('<span class="has-error help-block">' + val + '</sapn>')

                        //return false;
                    })
                    xhr.responseJSON = null;

                }
                return false;
            }
        })
        return false;
    })
});
```

Comment: Wonderful explanation.

Comment: Thank you for appreciation & accepting answer. Glad to help.